# How can I convert the resulting date format to another in django?

Tags: python, django, date, format

I am creating an app in django, and I have the next problem:

I have a Model that has an attribute "date", and I save the date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD.

But when I get an instance, and I get the date attribute value of that instance, the Date is: "Oct. 10, 2015", so that I get the error:

```
[u"'Oct.' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

How can I solve this error? Is there any way to format "Oct. 10, 2015" to YYYY-MM-DD?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For input `Oct. 10, 2015`, you need to write like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('Oct. 10, 2015', '%b. %d, %Y')
```

Django's DateField saves datetime object directly, so convert the input string to the required format.

You can try to input data like below using form:

```
class SomeForm(forms.modelform):
    date_input_field = forms.CharField()

    def clean_date_input_field(self):
        try: 
            return datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data['date_input_field'], '%d/%m/%Y')
        except:
             return datetime.strptime(self.cleaned_data['date_input_field'], '%b. %d, %Y')
     class Meta:
          ...
```

Or add `'%b. %d, %Y'` in [input_format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats).